# SQL replace does not work with phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I'd like to replace an url in my Wordpress database, but phpMyAdmin won't perform my sql code

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET post_content = replace (post_content, 'http://www.domain.de' , 'http://localhost/wordpress'); 

UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value = replace (meta_value, 'http://www.domain.de' , 'http://localhost/wordpress');
```

All I get is

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ï»¿' at line 1

I checked the SQl syntax but for me it seems to be right, could it be a problem with phpMyAdmin? (I am running 4.5.1)

Comment: Are you using phpmyadmin to do the query ? If the error said error in your SQL syntax why are you not showing it?

Comment: Are you trying to run both queries at the same time?

Comment: that there `ï»¿` is a BOM

Comment: `ï»¿` is also `ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE`, so it would be invisible.

Comment: @RickJames ah yes of course, that makes more sense. I thought it was a BOM which is also the same characters. I learned something today. I'll remember that one and have posted a community wiki answer quoting you.

Comment: @Fred-ii- - I think that same code (when at the start of the document) is used to clue in readers that the document is unicode.  (Hence, I said 'also'.)

Comment: @RickJames Given the question and the error, I'd say you were *spot on.*

Answer (score 0):

Posting as a community wiki.

As stated in comments:

> *ï»¿ is also ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE, so it would be invisible. – Rick James*

Reference:

- https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark
- A.k.a.: Byte Order Mark (BOM), but in this case, what failed you was just that, a ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE.

> *"The name BYTE ORDER MARK is an alias for the original character name ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE (ZWNBSP). With the introduction of U+2060 WORD JOINER, there's no longer a need to ever use U+FEFF for its ZWNSP effect, so from that point on, and with the availability of a formal alias, the name ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE is no longer helpful, and we will use the alias here."*